# Android Development - Gallery widget with text below

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery

I'm new to android development and I've gotten stuck.

I want to implement a scrolling list of images with text below each image.

I am trying to use the Gallery widget. I've succeeded in creating a gallery which I can load from a list of images off the memory card, but I can't figure how to place text under each image.

Is this possible? Perhaps a gallery is not the right widget for this.

Here's my main window code:

```
package org.touchandgo.speak;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class SpeakMainWindow extends LicenseCheckActivity  
{  
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

    private Uri[] mUrls;  
    String[] mFiles=null;  


    void showToast(String msg) {
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
    ad.setMessage(msg);
    ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ad.show();

}

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)  
    {  
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        } else {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }

    if (mExternalStorageAvailable)
    {
        File images = new File ( "/sdcard/TouchAndGoSpeech");

        showToast (images.getPath());



        File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {  
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
            {  
                return (name.endsWith(".jpg")||name.endsWith(".png"));  
            }  
        });

        mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];  

        for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)  
        {  
            mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();  
        }  
        mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];  

        for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)  
        {  
            mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);     
        }     

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.g_main);  
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  
        g.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
        g.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
        g.setSpacing(5);

    }
}  
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{  

    int mGalleryItemBackground;  
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)  {     
        mContext = c;     
    }  
    public int getCount(){  
        return mUrls.length;  
    }  
    public Object getItem(int position){  
        return position;  
    }  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){  
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);  
        i.setTag(mUrls[position]);
        i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);  
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(48, 48));

        return i;  
    }     
    private Context mContext;  
}     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your `getView()` method from your `ImageAdapter` to add a `LinearLayout` containing both the `ImageView` and the `TextView` you will use as a label, instead of just the ImageView.

Comment: Thanks Aleadam,

I can now display the image and the text for the image appears to the right of it, which actually isn't bad for my purposes, but I'd like the text to appear below the image.

I don't think I've fully grasped the getView concept.

Comment: Heres my code:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);

  ImageView i = new ImageView(ll.getContext());  
  i.setTag(mUrls[position]);
  i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);  
  i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
  i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(48, 48));
            
  TextView tv = new TextView(ll.getContext());
  tv.setTag(mFiles[position]);
  tv.setText(mFiles[position]);
  tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(48, 48));
            
  ll.addView(tv);
            
  return ll;  
}

Comment: You just need to set the orientation to vertical: `ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29